# Keycloak 18 with Quarkus as Windows Service

Tags: wildfly, keycloak, quarkus, windows-server

With Wildfly as an application server, it was possible to run KeyCloak as a service on a Windows Server as follows (for example behind an IIS):

```sh
.\service.bat install /name keycloak /display Keycloak /desc "Keycloak"
.\service.bat start /name Keycloak
```

Unfortunately, there is no `service.bat` anymore to run KeyCloak 18 as a service, since it'S backed with Quarkus now.

It seems, that there is only a `kc.bat`:

```sh
./kc.bat start
```

So, what's a propper way to run KeyCloak 18 with Quarkus as a service on a Windows Server?